# Checking whether (a/2) mod 2 is equal to (b/2)mod 2 , knowing (a mod p) and (b mod p) where p is a large prime like ((10^9)+7)?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$p$ is a large prime lets say $((10^9) +7)$.

I have two very large numbers  $a$ and $b$ but I know only the values of $a$ MOD $ p$ and $b$ MOD $p$.
Now I want to check whether $\frac{a}2$ MOD $2$ is the same as $\frac{b}2$ MOD $2$ ($\frac{a}2$ and $\frac{b}2$ are rounded to the nearest smaller integer). How to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to approach this is to check on a model situation with smaller $p$ (say, 17). Suppose you know only the value of $a\mod p$, and that is 1; $a$ itself is not known, it can be 1, 18, 35, 52 or whatever else. Can you tell what ${a\over2}\mod 2$ would be?

Comment: You are right it is not possible to check as I can't determine a/2 mod 2 itself.